# Two loops and move_uploaded_file, I am a bit confused

Tags: php, arrays, loops, session, foreach

There are two pages. Page 1 contains:

**Page1:**

```
$_SESSION['temporary'][$i] = $_FILES['img']['tmp_name'][$i];
$_SESSION['image'][$i] = $_FILES['img']['name'][$i];
```

Page 2 contains:

**Page2:**

```
for($i=0;$i<count($_SESSION['temporary']);$i++)
{
    echo '<br/>'.$_SESSION['temporary'][$i];
}

for($i=0;$i<count($_SESSION['image']);$i++)
{
    $path = $pre_path.'/'.basename($_SESSION['image'][$i]);
    echo '<br/>'.$_SESSION['image'][$i];
}
```

What I want to do is to use **move_uploaded_file** function like this:

```
move_uploaded_file($_SESSION['temporary'][$i], $path);
```

I can not use this function inside the second loop. because it will not contain

> $_SESSION['temporary'][$i]

from the first loop.

Why am I doing the script this way?
Because my script works in the following steps:

1. Page 0: Select category and properties, and upload images,
2. Page 1: Show selected categories and images encoded by base64,
3. Page 2: Insert to database everything.

I really do not have mind to do it. I will be very glad if someone help me, and ofcourse I accept the answer and give a thumb up.
If You find it more easy, you can use foreach loop instead:

```
foreach($_SESSION['temporary'] as $temporary)
{
    echo '<br/>'.$temporary;
}

foreach($_SESSION['image'] as $image)
{
    $path = $pre_path.'/'.basename($image);
    echo '<br/>'.$image;    
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<strike>On **page2** itself you can upload files like this:</strike>

```
$num_of_files = count($_SESSION['temporary']); // or count($_SESSION['image'])
for($i=0; $i < $num_of_files; $i++){
    echo '<br/>'.$_SESSION['temporary'][$i];
    echo '<br/>'.$_SESSION['image'][$i];
    $path = $pre_path.'/'.basename($_SESSION['image'][$i]);
    move_uploaded_file($_SESSION['temporary'][$i], $path);
}
```

Apparently I was wrong, you can't upload files like that.

From [the manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.move-uploaded-file.php),

> `move_uploaded_file()` function checks to ensure that the file designated by filename is a valid upload file (meaning that it was uploaded via PHP's HTTP POST upload mechanism). If the file is valid, it will be moved to the filename given by destination.

The `$_FILES` array only holds information about the file that has been uploaded *in this request*. If you do not save that file elsewhere within the same request, it will be removed by PHP at the end of the request. You cannot simply save `$_FILES['uploadfoto']['tmp_name']` into the session and expect the file to still be there later, because it won't be.

Comment: Nice, You have found the problem for loops, thank You. But files aren't uploaded. :(

Comment: No errors are appearing. But I've done something like: "  if(move_uploaded_file($_SESSION['temporary'][$i], $path))
  {
   echo 'uploaded';
  }
  else
  {
   echo 'upload failed';
  }"
and now it shows "upload failed".

Comment: @WojciechGlapa I've updated my answer. Please see the explanation.

Comment: Thank You so much! I've accepted an answer. What is the function to move temporary files to another folder? Maybe You know?

Comment: @WojciechGlapa `move_uploaded_file()` is the only function available to upload files i.e to move temporary files from predetermined directory to user specified directory.